# Showing positive and negative values in legend of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, legend

I want to draw this Legend by ArcGIS 10.2. This legend starts with a big blue circle and decreases in size till 0, then in 6 its bigger and red. I know its related to symbology and multiple attributes but which part could do it for me I don't know.

1. I can't show both red and blue circles together.
2. It starts with a big size and goes to smallest. I can set it by hand but its not completely same in both negative circles and positives circle because sometimes the intervals are not the same.

[image: stack].imgur.com/Rmckn.png

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE? Can you please *edit* your question and include the software (incl. version) you are using? Otherwise it is unlikely that we are able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a copy of your layer (right click the layer and choose copy then right-click the data frame and hit paste) and then use a definition query on each layer. for the first one set `"SOMEVALUE" >=  0` and then for the other it will be `"SOMEVALUE" <  0`. For the first one symbolize using graduated symbols and "Red[image]"

but then change number of classes to 3 and hit the classify button and change to manual classification and set it to 2, 6, and the max.
[image]

Now do the same for the negative numbers and make them blue.

**EDIT:** I see your comment and understand now that you have a second factor significant vs. not significant (sounds like statistics). I think you could adapt my answer but you will need 4 copies (instead of 2) and the 4 definition queries will need to change to

1. "SOMEVALUE" >= 0 AND "SIG" = 'SIG"  (THESE WOULD BE BLUE)
2. "SOMEVALUE" >= 0 AND "SIG" = 'NOT SIG"
3. "SOMEVALUE" < 0 AND "SIG" = 'SIG"  - (THESE WOULD BE RED)
4. "SOMEVALUE" < 0 AND "SIG" = ' NOT SIG"  - (THESE WOULD BE RED)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It s not possible for my data. I have two factor to show for each city. the first is trend which could be negative(blue) or positive(red). the second is the significant of them: not significant(empty)  significant (filled) circle for both red and blue circle. because of that I used  multiple attributes. I can show it by multiple attributes but for Legend I have a lots of definition in legend!!!!

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a new field such as "CombinedScore" and collapse the two variables down to one for symbolizing. It's easier using graduated/proportional symbols on one "combined" field rather than 2-3 separate fields.

Comment: Thank you John for your answer. I didn't get your solution. Would you please explain it more or introduce a reference to read.